# NSURLSession takes too much time

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsoperationqueue

I'm using NSURLSession to post a request. Although I'm setting queue to main queue still it takes too much time to respond

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:LOGIN_SERVICE]];

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];

[dataTask resume];
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561021/nsurlsession-is-taking-longer-time-than-nsurlconnection-for-simple-post-request) but it has only one answer which is similar to what I'm doing. Anything that I'm missing ?

Comment: downvotes ? becoz I mentioned ther's another question without answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you update question with code required, I will say nothing apparently here which make your request slow, few things as this is Network request, it will depend on different things like network speed, server response time. It would be worth while testing on different networks devices.

Comment: It's complete I haven't added it yet as there's nothing I'm doing in there which will take time. I'll edit my question

Comment: does your request gets timeout...? our you getting an error

Comment: No I'm getting the response It's taking a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetworking. If your response like this

```
{
  "my_response": {"name": "XXX","area": "XXX","num": "XXX"
  },
  "other_response": {"message": "Hello","status": "success","flag_value": "1"
  }
}
```

Stpe 1 :- And set time interval also.

```
- (void)yourMethod{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", your_service_url];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

   AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
   [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

   NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                           your_parameters_list,
                            nil];
        NSMutableURLRequest *jsonRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                path:urlString
                                                          parameters:params];

    [jsonRequest setTimeoutInterval:120];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:jsonRequest success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@" Success %@", JSON);

        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary1 = [JSON valueForKey:@"my_response"];
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary2 = [JSON valueForKey:@"other_response"];

                NSString* name = [jsonDictionary1 valueForKey:@“name”];
                NSString* area = [jsonDictionary1 valueForKey:@"name"];
                NSString* num =  [jsonDictionary1 valueForKey:@"num"];




    } failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Fail %@", [error userInfo]);

        NSLog(@“Error %@", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);


    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: I wan't asking for a substitue